# Software Updater crashes on Xfce only

Tags: 20.04, xfce, update-manager, crash

**TL;DR:** The only clue I could find in the logs is that on a working system `/var/log/syslog` reports `AptDaemon`'s transactions like this: queuing - simulating - processing - finished. On my system it stops on 'simulating'.

**Long version**

The problem manifested after the upgrade from 18.04 that had Xfce 4.12 to 20.04 with its Xfce 4.14. Since 20.04 also had Software Updater remade to include snaps, I can't attribute the issue to Xfce only.

Software Updater works fine with the standard Gnome 3 on Xorg, Gnome 3 on Wayland, Gnome Flashback - all on the same Ubuntu installation. On Xfce, the following happens:

1. The list of packages to install and remove is displayed correctly.
2. After I click 'Install', the words "waiting for auth..." (can't read the rest this fast, but the idea is clear) appear for a split second and Software Updater closes.

Tried reinstalling this and that as suggested by Google; no dice. Of course, I can dance around it with the console. Would prefer to fix it, though.

**ETA**

Fixed by installing `policykit-1-gnome`. I'm still curious about the root cause.